# Speed Up Magento Site

Tags: magento-1.9, websites

Im using a magento site with 1.9.1 version and the site is very slow.
At googlespeedsight im getting 55-60% at gmetrix its better but its 70% but the page load speed is very slow.
There are two main option: Add Expires headers,Leverage browser caching.
I've searched a lot but i can only find one solution what is to add some expire code the htaccess file.I did it but Leverage browser caching only increased to 6%
from 0%, Expires headers didnt change(still zero).
How could i increase this,is there other solution?

Also Minify JavaScript and CSS is only 30% and combine images usin css is 0%, other Minify JavaScript is 65%,optimize images 80% while i use Cloudflare plus
my site is still very slow.

What have i done to increase:
1.Use Business Cloud serves.
2.Use Cloudflare plus.
3.Use SiteGround's SuperCacher
4.At Cpanel i enabled compress all data.
5.At magento admin panel i enabled Merge Javascript and CSS.
6.At magento i enabled Compilation.

I searched on google for days but i only find these as main changes to do to speed up the site.

Answer (score 1):

4 Simple but Effective Ways to Improve Magento’s Performance

1. Enable Flat Categories and Products

In Magento admin, (top menu) System > Configuration, (left nav) Catalog > Catalog, (main page) Frontend.  Set “Use Flat Catalog Category” and “Use Flat Catalog Product” to “Yes“.

Attributes that apply to Categories and Products are stored in separate database tables depending on their dataypes. ‘Flattening’ will put all attributes in one table for Magento retrieve. This will have a positive impact on site speed especially if it has 1,000 or more products

2. Merge CSS and JS Files

In Magento admin, (top menu) System > Configuration, (left nav) Advanced > Developer, (main page) JavaScript Settings, CSS Settings. Set “Merge Javascript” Files and “Merge CSS” Files to “Yes”.

A Magento site can have many CSS and javascript files and there will be more that come with extensions and site customizations. Doing step #2, will combine all CSS and javascript into one file which will make each page load faster.

3. Enable Compilation

In Magento admin, (top menu) System > Tools > Compilation, click Enable. This will take all the active scripts in Magento’s core structure and bring them to the front for faster website speed.

If updates, code modifications, extension installations are needed, Compilation needs to be disabled first. If not, there will be errors.

4. Caching Magento

When all other settings are in place and the site is ready to go live, go to System > Cache Management. Select all items, set the Action dropdown to “Enable” then hit Submit

The above settings will help increase the performance of an average Magento website. Those who are accustomed to server administration can do more. There are caching extensions that can be incorporated within Magento’s configuration file and other server tricks to speed up Magento.

Comment: Thank you but i alrady done with 2. and 3. as i wrote it down and 1. Crashed my site categories dissapeard.

Comment: Strictly speaking, on the later versions of Magento, Compilation really doesn't do much.

Comment: Also please note that the total perceantage on gtmetrix is about 88-90% which is better than facebook's but the page loading time is about 5 and its very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on how technically minded you are, I've found quite a great deal of success using Varnish Cache. Varnish has to be set up on the server first, and then you can use this free Magento module to manage it via the Magento interface.

If you're not technically minded, it may be something you speak to your server administrator about. Varnish can be incredibly powerful when configured correctly, and I've seen brilliant results of caching using this across a range of sites (one had 100,000 products)

http://www.nexcess.net/resources/plugins/magento-turpentine-varnish

There are also others that allow this kind of management of Varnish, but I would recommend the Nexcess one over these, below:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html

Comment: Im not too minded but i will look it up,thank.Im using other cacher i hope it wont be problem.However i already achived 90% at gtmetrix and 70% at google speed sight what as i mentioned way better than other sites and i dont what else could i prove because every secition seems to be good.
According to gtmetrix i can only improve the followings:
-Specify image dimensions
-Combine images using CSS sprites
-Minify JavaScript and CSS
-Configure entity tags (ETags)
-Use cookie-free domains

I think the sites because problem is to manage many images.(Have 20.000product with over 100.000images)

Comment: It just turned out that i already use varnish cacher.Its been installed under name SuperCacher at Cpnale but its the same.

Comment: If Varnish is installed then, you'll want to get the Nexcess extension to allow you to configure it properly for Magento.

Comment: Hello
Do you think to this:
http://www.nexcess.net/resources/plugins/magento-turpentine-varnish
If yes i installed and crashed my whole site and admin panel as well my hosting server could fix it but the extension is still there and it cant be uninstalled(at least not from admin panel)
My varnish extension called Supercacher created my Siteground(my hosting provider)

Comment: Ah, you already have a Varnish extension built into Magneto then? You didn't mention this, only that you had Varnish installed on Cpanel. SSH into the server and delete the module files.